# QT QML how to create a reusable button component

Tags: qt, qml, components

I have some simulated buttons in on rectangle. These buttons I need at different places in the app. Is it possible to make a kind of component out of it?

This is how it is currently

```
RowLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent

    Rectangle {
        id: button1
        height: _buttonsHeight * 0.6
        width: height
        radius: height / 2
        border.width: 1
        border.color: "black"

        Image {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            source: "image://iconProvider/icons/128/button1.png"
            sourceSize.height: parent.height * 0.8
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPressed: btnHome.border.width = 2
            onReleased: btnHome.border.width = 0
            onClicked: userInputDevice.buttonClicked("button1")
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: button2
        height: _buttonsHeight * 0.6
        width: height
        radius: height / 2
        border.width: 1
        border.color: "black"

        Image {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            source: "image://iconProvider/icons/128/button2.png"
            sourceSize.height: parent.height * 0.8
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPressed: btnHome.border.width = 2
            onReleased: btnHome.border.width = 0
            onClicked: userInputDevice.buttonClicked("button2")
        }
    }
}
```

Something like this would be the goal

```
RowLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent
    Button {id = "button1", height = _buttonsHeight * 0.6, icon = "button1.png", command = "button1", parent = this}
    Button {id = "button2", height = _buttonsHeight * 0.6, icon = "button2.png", command = "button2", parent = this}
}
```

Is something like this feasible ?

Thanks and best regards

Arne

Answer (score 1):

You should read the documentation about [QML defining types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-documents-definetypes.html).

Don't use the assignment operator, but the colon to create bindings. No need to set any parent.

For the nested `Image.source` property you should create an alias property in the root of your component like so `property alias imageSource: <imageID>.source` to be able to set it from the outside.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Layouts

Window {
    id: root
    width: 320
    height: 240
    visible: true

    property int btnHeight: 80

    component CustomButton : Rectangle {
        property alias icon: image.source
        signal pressed
        signal released
        signal clicked

        id: buttonRoot
        height: 20
        width: height
        radius: height / 2
        border.width: 1
        border.color: "black"

        Image {
            id: image
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            source: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/72/Variable_Resistor.svg"
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            width: buttonRoot.height / Math.sqrt(2)
            height: image.width
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPressed: buttonRoot.pressed()
            onReleased: buttonRoot.released()
            onClicked: buttonRoot.clicked()
        }
    }

    RowLayout {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        spacing: 20

        CustomButton {
            id: button1
            height: root.btnHeight
            onClicked: console.log("Button 1 clicked")
        }
        CustomButton {
            id: button2
            height: root.btnHeight
            icon: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Crystal_Clear_app_download_manager.svg"
            onClicked: console.log("Button 2 clicked")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I have been QML'ing for years now, but never saw the inline component syntax. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello Peter, thank you very much for your answer. I am still in the early stages of QML. What do you mean with the image source? I use an IconProvider, which is set up so far. I would only have to pass the name of the icon to the button and the button would then have to load the icon via the IconProvider.

Comment: `IconProvider` or not doesn't matter. All I was showing is how to forward properties to the outside from nested items in the component in order to be able to set/bind them from the outside. Have a look at the example I've shared the `icon` property in the `CustomButton` component.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new qml file let's name it MyButton.qml

MyButton is a custom button with icon and text you can change it to fit your needs.

MyButton.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import Qt.labs.platform 1.0
import QtLocation 5.12
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15


MouseArea {
    id: control
    width: control.w
    height: control.h
    property string icon_btn
    property bool icon_visible: true
    property string text
    property int border: 3
    property string borderColor: "white"
    property string colorr: "#222222"
    property int w: 50
    property int h: 50
    property bool text_visible: true
    property bool clicked: false
    property int radius: 12
    property int contentLeftMargin: 0
    property string buttonColor: enabled ? control.colorr : "grey"

    cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor

    Rectangle {
        border.color: control.borderColor
        border.width: control.border
        radius: control.radius
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: control.buttonColor

        RowLayout{
            anchors.fill: parent

            Item { Layout.fillWidth: true }
            Image{
                id: img
                visible: control.icon_visible
                source: control.icon_btn
                Layout.preferredWidth: 35
                Layout.preferredHeight: 35
                //Layout.leftMargin: control.contentLeftMargin
            }
            Text{
                id: txt
                text: control.text
                font.pointSize: 17
                font.bold: true
                color: "white"
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                visible: control.text_visible ? x + width + 15 < control.width : 0
                //Layout.leftMargin: control.contentLeftMargin
            }
            Item { Layout.fillWidth: true }
        }
    }
    Layout.bottomMargin: 10
}
```

Then use it in your main qml file.

For example:

```
Window {

    MyButton{
        id: btn_refresh
        icon_btn: "qrc:/Icons/outline_refresh_white_48pt_3x.png"
        
        onClicked: {
            //do something on click
        }
    }
}
```